# Lyapunov invariant set for affine systems

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, control-theory, invariant-theory, invariance

Given a linear system $\dot{x}=Ax$ such that the real part of every eigenvalue of $A$ is less than $0$, Lyapunov's equation $A^T P + P A = -Q$ with $Q$ being any suitably sized positive definite matrix gives us an invariant ellipsoid $x^T P x \leq 1$, i.e. for any initial state $x_0$ such that $x_0^T P x_0 \leq 1$ we know that the states $x$ or rather $x(t)$ (making dependency to $t$ explicit) reachable from $x_0$ remain inside the invariant ellipsoid, i.e. $x(t)^T P x(t) \leq 1 ~\forall t \geq t_0$.

How can this be generalized to affine systems $\dot{x}=Ax + b$ where the real part of every eigenvalue of $A$ is less than $0$? Clearly, transforming the affine system into a linear system by extending state vector by $b$ with $\dot{b}=0$ does not help since we will have eigenvalue(s) $0$ which violates our assumption.

Comment: If $A$ is still non-singular, then you can just make a shift $x = y + A^{-1}b$. And this will lead to system $\dot{y} = Ay$ for which everything is already known.

Comment: You are right but it should be $y=x+A^{-1}b$ and thus $\dot{y}=\dot{x}$. Since all eigenvalues are less than 0, it follows that $A$ is non-singular. Hence, your proposal solved the problem. If you want to write it as a solution, I will accept it.

Comment: Just to make it perfectly explicit: $y=x+A^{-1}b \Leftrightarrow x = y - A^{-1}b$ and thus $\dot{y} = \dot{x} = A x + b = A (y - A^{-1} b) + b = A y - b + b = A y$

Comment: Yep, sorry, I overlooked the wrong sign :)

Comment: Evgeny: Would you like to write an answer? If not, I will write one for documentation purposes and refer to your comment.

Comment: For me it's too short and simple observation for the full answer. I'm glad that I've already helped you, so you can document it yourself :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Evgeny suggested, it is enough to translate the coordinate system, i.e. for $x=y-A^{-1} b$ we have $\dot{y} = \dot{x} = A x + b = A (y - A^{-1} b) + b = A y - b + b = A y$ and thus the invariant ellipsoid is $y^T P y = (x+A^{-1}b)^T P (x+A^{-1}b) \leq 1$. Note that $A^{-1}$ exists since we demanded that the real part of every eigenvalue of $A$ is less than $0$ and it holds that a matrix is invertible if and only if it has no eigenvalue which is $0$.